# puppeteer-cluster, different data to the same url

Tags: javascript, bots, puppeteer, puppeteer-cluster

i put an example below that i want to add different search inputs (firstWord + scndWord) from array of object to two google pages in the same time, so opening pages dynamically depend on the array length
1st page open google then write red flower
2nd page open google but write 'gaming PC

```
        const { Cluster } = require('puppeteer-cluster');
        (async () => {
        const cluster = await Cluster.launch({
            concurrency: Cluster.CONCURRENCY_PAGE,
            maxConcurrency: 10,
            puppeteerOptions: {
                headless: false,
            },
            
        });
        cluster.on('taskerror', (err, url) => {
            console.error((new Date()).toJSON() + `  Error crawling ${url}: ${err.message}`);
        });

        const arr = [
            {firstWord: 'gaming ',scndWord: 'pc'},
            {firstWord: 'red ', scndWord: 'flower'}
        ]


        await cluster.task(async ({ page, data: index }) => {

            await page.goto('https://www.google.com/');
            await page.focus('body > div.L3eUgb > div.o3j99.ikrT4e.om7nvf > form > div:nth-child(1) > div.A8SBwf > div.RNNXgb > div > div.a4bIc > input')
            await page.keyboard.type('flower');
            await page.waitForNavigation()

            await page.screenshot({ path: 'screenshot.png', fullPage: true })

        });

         for (let index = 0; index <=arr.length -1 ; index++) {
cluster.execute(index);}
```

I'm confusing how to do that, i will be thankful for the help

Answer (score 0):

i got it

```
        const { Cluster } = require('puppeteer-cluster');


    (async () => {
    const cluster = await Cluster.launch({
        concurrency: Cluster.CONCURRENCY_PAGE,
        maxConcurrency: 10,
        puppeteerOptions: {
            headless: false,
        },
        
    });
    cluster.on('taskerror', (err, url) => {
        console.error((new Date()).toJSON() + `  Error crawling ${url}: ${err.message}`);
    });

    const arr = [
        {firstWord: 'gaming ',scndWord: 'pc'},
        {firstWord: 'red ', scndWord: 'flower'}
    ]


    await cluster.task(async ({ page, data: [firstWord , scndWord] }) => {

        await page.goto('https://www.google.com/');
        await page.focus('body > div.L3eUgb > div.o3j99.ikrT4e.om7nvf > form > div:nth-child(1) > div.A8SBwf > div.RNNXgb > div > div.a4bIc > input')
        await page.keyboard.type(firstWord + scndWord);
        await page.waitForNavigation()

        await page.screenshot({ path: 'screenshot.png', fullPage: true })

    });


    arr.map((serach)=>{
        cluster.execute([serach.firstWord, serach.scndWord]);
    })

    //   await cluster.idle();
    //   await cluster.close();
    })();
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).